# state containing storage data not rerendering as storage data changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a class A in which I'm making an Ajax call.
After receiving the response, I'm updating the storage.

```
class A {
    $.ajax({
        url
        success: (response) => {
            if (responseData !== null) {
                storage.set('view', true);
            } 
        },
        error: (jqXHR, status, error) => {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}
```

There is another class B, in which I have put this storage in state.

```
class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            view: storage.get('view')
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="test"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want class B to rerender if ajax call in class A is not null but it's not happening. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `B` component will only be re-rendered if its `state` of `props` change. What kind of storage is `storage`?

Comment: storage is sessionStorage 

Isn't state changing here?

Comment: the best way to share storage/data between components in react is redux/mobx.
class A should set to redux , redux will cause class B to render when state of redux is bound to it.

Comment: we are not using redux in our app as of now.

Comment: State is not changing when the `storage` change after the network request, since `B`'s `componentDidMount` will most likely run before the network request is complete.

Comment: hmm.. probably yes. but that time view should have undefined. 
so as we receive response, it should be updated and hence rerender itself.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is what you want to accomplish, but there is nothing linking a change in the sessionStorage to your `B` component in your code. You can't put the logic in the `A` class in the `B` component instead?

Comment: As per my understanding, storage is pointing to some memory location lets say XXXX and B's state is referring this memory location.
Now as data at XXXX is updated, B's state should also get updated and hence rerender.
Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: class B render if props change / state change .
class B is not re-render if storage change , no matter the memory location. Redux/Mobx is the way to go here. or implementing some sort of parent container component and share a func , that will trigger forceUpdate

Comment: but storage is in the state, it will still not be taken as state change?

Comment: No, because state is immutable - it take the storage copy. not reference to the storage. ( I think )

Comment: When you do `this.setState({ view: storage.get('view') })` you get value present in the storage at that time in the `state` of `B`. It doesn't update automatically.

Comment: ah.. that's right.
So only way forward is using redux? Any other workaround would be preferable

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the proper context. Could you include your entire `A` class and `B` component in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You might want to keep that logic in `B` instead, or use a state management library like MobX/Redux if that is not feasible.

Comment: problem with keeping the logic in B is, API call will be delayed. I want to send API call in the beginning so that we do not need to wait for it's response. But looks like that's the only option or move to redux. 
Anyways, thanks. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Tholle Just read this article, https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c 

"The problem in this sample code, as you may have guessed, is that in Javascript objects and arrays are passed as reference. This means that when we say updatedPassengers=this.state.passengers we’re not making a copy of the array — we are just creating a new reference to the same array that is in the current component’s state. Further on, by using the array method push, we end up mutating its state directly."

this makes me think again

Comment: @Bailey A boolean is not an array, and even if you mutated an array in a component's state, it would still not re-render, because a component will only re-render if the state changes with the help of `setState` or if its `props` change.

Comment: That's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

React components with redux share:

```
 class Login extends Component {
    handleSubmitForm = ({values}) => {
       fetch("http://server.com/login", fetchData).then(
        response.json().then(response => {
        setUserDetails(response); // this function save to redux
      })        
    }
    render() {
      return <button onClick={this.handleSubmitForm} />
    }
 }
 export Login;

 class B extends Component {
  render() {
      return <div>running when props changes</div>
  }
 }
 // this is the redux mapping - will cause to class B to re-render when redux 
 // User Details changes
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   userDetails: state.userDetails
 });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(B);
```